# I don't know how to use 'as'

Tags: grammar, as

does 'I introduce someone as something' mean 'I introduce someone as I am something' or 'I introduce someone as he is something'?

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, the *as* would usually refer to the person being introduced, and to note that *you* are something, you'd be expected to use different phrasing:

> As the captain of FC Smalltown, I introduce John Smith, our new striker.

But there are cases where the *as* would refer to you, the introducer:

> Tomorrow, I'm going to introduce John as his manager.

So in the grammar sense, it can be ambiguous - but unless the context makes it very clear that the *as*-part refers to yourself, it'll probably be understood to refer to the introducee.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of British English?

Comment: @GKK No (or any other English for that matter), why?

Comment: Oh sorry I mistook you as Michal Harvey. Sorry.